# How to share a text link via text intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sharing

I want to share a text clicking on which the user will navigate to a url via android share intent.

**For example:**

"Visit [google](http://google.com) for more info."

In above text, on clicking google, user will be redirected to google.com. I need to achieve something like this instead of showing the user the complete url. What i have tried is making it an html link with href which doesnt work.

So, How should i achieve it?

Answer (score 11):

You must be using the type as `plain text` i.e, :

```
intent.setType("text/plain");
```

set the type to html like this :

```
intent.setType("text/html");
```

and it'll work.

So, you can use this to share a html text :

```
String textToShare = "Visit <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">google</a> for more info.";
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

intent.setType("text/html");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "sample");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(textToShare));

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));
```

**OUTPUT** :

Here's a screenshot from the Gmail app :

[image: Screenshot from Gmail app]

Comment: it doesn't shows whatsap  or fb messenger to share. :/

Comment: so there's no way you can do this for such apps, however you can do this for email apps like Gmail.

Comment: check the screenshot in the updated answer, is it what you want?

Comment: yes it is. but i need it on all apps like whatsap, fb messenger n all.

Comment: yeah so as i said there's no way you can do this for such apps. You'll have to share plain text i.e, with `text/plain` mime type to be able to share text in such apps and it will not be formatted like this.

Comment: it seems doesn't work nowadays with newest Android versions

Answer (score 2):

[Visit google](http://www.google.com)

Use a `href` tag
and set Text here with `Html.fromHtml();` and set to textview

Comment: did you try it what i said

Comment: yup. It works same as the above answer. It cannot share content via whasap or fb messenger.

Answer (score -1):

try like this:

use text view selection and long press listener to call share intent. otherwise you can use android spannable textview.

Refer this link for spannable textview with google search: http://androidcocktail.blogspot.in/2014/03/android-spannablestring-example.html

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/#q=selected word here");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: this is not share intent. I need to share the text, not directly open it on browser.